# whats the purpose of keeping copy of an element in memory using .detach() method in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, methods

I am just going through [.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) and [.detach()](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) method in jQuery. 
It says that .remove() method removes all matched elements in the DOM.
But in case of [.detach()](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) it is same as [.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) but keeps the copy of them in memory.

So, **could you please tell me what's the purpose of keeping the copy of those elements in memory?**

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/remove/: “In addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed. To remove the elements without removing data and events, use .detach() instead.”

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of keeping the copy is to be able to re-insert the element(s) back into the DOM at a later point in time (after some other processing has taken place). For example:-

```
<table id="table-test">
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
</table>

<button id="detach-one">Detach Test One</button>
<button id="detach-two">Detach Test Two</button>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#detach-one").click(function () {
            $("#table-test tr").remove();
        });

        $("#detach-two").click(function () {
            var hold = $("#table-test tr:first").detach();
            $("#table-test tr").remove();
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#table-test").append(hold);
            }, 2000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

`#detach-one` removes all `<tr>` in the table and they're gone.

`#detach-two` holds the first `<tr>` and reinserts it at a future point in time.

See [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) for more detail.